# unable to display Notification when PC is locked

Tags: javascript, notifications, google-cloud-messaging, service-worker

I am currently working on a desktop notification system using GCM and service workers.

Aside from some issues with some PC's not receiving the notifications (working on it), it's been pretty successful and I can send messages while Chrome is open or closed, and use an API to grab some dynamic data to display.

The issue that I am hoping someone might be able to help me with is that if I send a notification to the PC while the PC is locked, the user doesn't receive the notification when they log back in.

Once they have logged back in, if I send another notification to them, it will display the notification that was sent when the PC was locked.

Does anyone know if it is possible to have the notification appear when the user unlocks the PC?

Thanks folks.